# How pro-grammatically can verify the permissions on an object and its fields?

Tags: permissions

How pro-grammatically can I verify the permissions on an object and its fields?
I also need to find -programmatically- objects with no permission set through profiles or permission sets?

Comment: Jose, can you give us a bit more context on your needs? What is the objective? To check a specific page or to do a thorough review of the org?

Answer (score 1):

You can use de DescribeSObjectResult class to check accessibility for objects and fields. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm).

There is an existing project [Force.com ESAPI](https://code.google.com/archive/p/force-dot-com-esapi) that is a work from Salesforce Labs, available for the OWASP foundation too.

Here you have the [link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009x7hPEAQ) to the package.

To check for the permission sets check [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html).